# Area of parabola using "weighted" average?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was watching an online lecture of calculus when the professor was going over 3 ways of preforming numerical integration; these were Riemann Sums, the Trapezoid Rule, and the Simpson's Rule. When explaining the Simpson's Rule he used a formula for the area of the parabola with three points $y_1,y_2,$ and $y_3$ where $y_1$ and $y_3$ were the ends of it and $y_2$ would be there midpoint. The formula was

$$2\Delta x(\frac{y_1+4y_2+y_3}{6})$$

where $2\Delta x$ was the width and the rest of the equation was the "weighted" average height. I understand why he used $2 \Delta x$ as his base but cannot seem to find how to derive this "weighted" average without using any integration (It kinda cause a loop where you define an integral using the area of parabola defined by an integral ...). I have seen  Archimedes' Quadrature of the Parabola but cannot seem to to find a way to use it to derive this utterly strange and "weighted" average height.

Comment: $y2$ is not the ordinate of the peak, but of the point whose abscissa is the same as the midpoint between the endpoints.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proved by using Archimedes' Theorem, stating that the area of parabolic segment $P_1P_2P_3$ is $4/3$ the area of triangle $P_1P_2P_3$ (see picture below). Notice first of all that the area $S_{tot}$ comprised between parabolic arc $P_1P_2P_3$ and the $x$ axis, by Archimedes' theorem can be written as:
$$
S_{tot}=S_{ACP_3P_1}+{4\over3}S_{P_3P_1P_2},
$$
where I denote by $S_{P_3P_1P_2}$ the area of polygon ${P_3P_1P_2}$ and so on, that is
$$
S_{tot}=S_{ACP_3P_1}+{4\over3}(S_{ABP_2P_1}+S_{BCP_3P_2}-S_{ACP_3P_1})
={1\over3}(4S_{ABP_2P_1}+4S_{BCP_3P_2}-S_{ACP_3P_1}).
$$
Substitute now here $S_{ABP_2P_1}=\Delta x(y_2+y_1)/2$, 
$S_{BCP_3P_2}=\Delta x(y_2+y_3)/2$ and $S_{ACP_3P_1}=2\Delta x(y_3+y_1)/2$
to obtain your formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was a very intuitive and well done solution.

Comment: Got a doubt, shouldn't P2, be the vertex of the segment of the parabola? (farthest point from  the line segment P1, P3, on the parabola), for Archimedes' theorem to be true?

Comment: After googling that theorem, I found a proof here (http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/JAC/NYB/exhaustion2.pdf). But in the proof, the triangle formed inside the segment, contains the vertex of the segment (farthest point from the chord, on the parabola). But in Simpson's rule, we are given three points, so there's no necessity for the middle point to be the vertex of the segment. Therefore how is this answer, valid, what am I missing?

Comment: @AravindhVasu Point $P_2$ in my answer IS the farthest point from chord $P_1P_3$, because the tangent line at $P_2$ is parallel to $P_1P_3$

Comment: @Aretino but in Simpson's rule, we are **given** three points right? So what if the middle points not the farthest?

Comment: @AravindhVasu It is a general property of any parabola: if from the midpoint of a chord we draw a line parallel to the axis, intersecting the parabola at , then the tangent at  is parallel to the chord. You can prove that easily in analytic geometry, but synthetic proofs are also possible.

Comment: @AravindhVasu For a simple geometric proof, see for instance this answer to another question: math.stackexchange.com/a/3515250/255730

Comment: Ahh, yes sorry, my mistake is, I thought, that  we are provided discrete points, but we actually choose the points. My bad, thank you for your patience.

Comment: Another small doubt, Is this theorem (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdvII0x0Y58) in anyway related to the one stated above? In other words, does the line drawn parallel to the axis of symmetry from the point where the tangents intersect, meet the parabola, at the vertex of the segment?

Comment: @AravindhVasu Yes, if by "vertex" you mean the farthest point, i.e. the point where the tangent is parallel to the chord. See my proof linked above: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3515250/255730

Comment: Wow thanks,  so from that video, we have that Area of segment = 2/3 (area of triangle AIB), Now can we got to prove, Area of APB = 2 (Area of AIB) to prove Area of segment = 4/3 (area of triangle APB),

Comment: By the way: I'd rather recommend this page for a proof of Archimedes' theorem: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ArchimedesTriangle.shtml

Comment: Thank you for your patience.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DdNAcv_rezc answer animated :)

Answer (score 0):

If $y=f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is the equation of the parabola, let us compute

$$f(x_1)+4f\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)+f(x_2)=$$

$$=a \left(x_1^2+4f\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)^2+x_2^2 \right)+b(x_1+4(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2})+x_2)+6c$$

When you expand this expression, you get:

$$a(2x_1^2+2x_2^2+2x_1x_2)+b(3x_1+3x_2)+6c$$

Now divide it by $6$ and multiply it by $\Delta x := x_2-x_1$:

(note: my $\Delta x$ is your $2\Delta x$).

$$(x_2-x_1) \ \left[\dfrac{1}{3}a(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2)+\dfrac{1}{2}b(x_1+x_2)+c \right] $$

you obtain
$$ \dfrac{1}{3}a(x_2^3-x_1^3)+\dfrac{1}{2}b(x_2^2-x_1^2)+c(x_2-x_1)$$

which coincides with

$$\int_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2}(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\left[a \dfrac{x^3}{3} + b \dfrac{x^2}{2} + cx \right]_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2}$$

Edit: following a discussion with Ziad Fakhoury, there is no true intuitive rationale behind the 1/6, 4/6, 1/6 coefficients.

Besides, it should be known that there is a more general theory that includes this list of weights as a particular case: it is the theory of [Newton-Cotes formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html): for example, instead of choosing one point $m$ in the middle between $x_1$ and $x_2$, you can choose for example two: $m_1=(2x_1+x_2)/3$ and $m_2=(x_1+2x_2)/3$, splitting interval $(x_1,x_2)$ into three equal-length intervals, instead of two ; in this case, the corresponding Newton-Cotes formula is $$(x_2-x_1) \dfrac{f(x_1)+3f(m_1)+3f(m_2)+f(x_2)}{8}$$ (weights $1/8, 3/8, 3/8, 1/8$) giving an exact value of the integral $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)dx$ for any polynomial function $f$ of degree at most 4.

Comment: Yes this works well, but as I mention I would like to prove why this is the "weighted" average without the use of integration.

Comment: I don't understand your remark: integration is only at the end to verify the formula...

Comment: I'm sorry if i am missing the obvious here but then how does your first computation give the "weighted" average of height. It'll be helpful also if you explain what is meant by a "weighted" average.

Comment: In order to simplify the computation, I have introduced the 1/6 later in the computations. I begin by combining $f(x_1), f(m), f(x_2)$ with resp. factors $1,4,1$ and, three lines after, these become $1/6, 4/6, 1/6$ which sum up to 1: thus it is equivalent to a weighted average.

Comment: In order to fully answer your question, a normal (arthmetic) average of three quantities is $(f_1+f_2+f_3)/3$ whereas a weighted average say with weights 4,7,3 is $(4f_1+7f_2+3f_3)/(4+7+3)$

Comment: Ok, thanks again for bearing with me, i understand what you have done and it makes sense to me know, however why does f(m) have a weight of 4 in this case? Is it some property of parabolas?

Comment: I am going to make an edit to my answer in order to "explain" it.