# Significance of 4 in the height of of the parabola (in Simpson's formula)

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric, average

I am doing the single variable calculus lecture from the MIT OpenCourseWare, in one lecture when they were teaching about the numerical integrations—more specifically, the Simpson's rule. In the lecture, they gave a formula for the average height (or weighted average height) of a parabola: $\frac{Y_0 + 4Y_1 + Y_2}{6}$). I didn't understand the formula "very well"; when I googled it, I found [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804694/area-of-parabola-using-weighted-average) on the stack that was asking the same question—I guess he didn't understand that lecture very well as well. But the proof given in the post went straight over my head, but I found a video on the Simpson's formula by Eddie Woo; it cleared the derivation part. Still, I am confused by the formula, and what it is signifying.

How can the middle of height—so to say—be more weighted than the others, what is that 4 signifying in the formula? I am not able to understand that.

PS, I don't how to add equations using LaTex.

Comment: (+1) for researching similar questions first. That said, please take a few minutes to look over the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) it is really quite simple and is practically a must have skill if you want your future questions on the MSE to be well received.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that 

Comment: @Moo Thank you for the link. The thing that I am trying to understand is, the height of the parabola is called "weighted average"—as per my knowledge, and I believe that the 4 in the average is a weight that is assigned by the integration. The thing that is bothering me, why give 4x Importance to the mid-height—so to speak, and not the rest. It is mathematically correct, I am not challenging that, but why is it saying that?

Comment: The average of a function $f(x)$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is defined as: $${1\over b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx.$$ Substitute $f(x)$ with the quadratic function used in Simpson's rule and you'll get that result. There is nothing mysterious here.